# RotateY on page hover

Tags: html, css, transform

I'm trying to have an image rotate on the Y axis on hover. I have following code that is working on -moz- but not on -webkit- or -o-. Am I missing something?

```
.spin-logo {
  height: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -moz-transition: transform 2000ms ease 0s;
  -o-animation: transform  2000ms ease 0s;    
  -webkit-animation: transform 2000ms ease 0s;
  animation: animation 2000ms linear ease 0s;
}
.spin-logo:hover {
  -moz-transform: rotateY(360deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(360deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
}
```

Comment: please don't accept below answer that doesn't fix you issue ... you need to use transition and not animation ! that's all ...

Answer (score -1):

I guess I needed to look a little closer. Needed to change -o-animation: and -webkit-animation to transitions. Problem solved.